# Visual Studio 2013 - background color based on file type

Tags: visual-studio-2013, themes

I would like to visualize when I´m working backend or frontend with different colors. For an example, when I am working in .cs files the background should be black, and when I am working in .js files the background should be dark blue.
I cannot find a way to achieve this. It would be nice if you could change the color based on the codefiles extension.

Does any of you know how?

Comment: Would love to have this. Notepad++ JavaScript color is what I prefer.